# browser does not show message before a javascript function completes its execution

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created a plugin to display a busy indicator in DOM elements like body or divs, but im having a problem with the situation bellow

```
$("body").BusyIndicator(true,"Please wait")

validateAndSubmitForm(); 

$("body").BusyIndicator(true,"Saving")
```

The problem is the first message **"Please wait"** isn't shown, the function **validateAndSubmitForm** seems to block the browser, and when it is unlocked, show directly the message **"Saving"**

Someone knows how can i ensure that the first message really are displayed before to execute the function validateAndSubmitForm ?

Comment: Without showing us your plugin source this will be sort of foretelling...

Comment: I guess your validateAndSubmitForm is Asynchonize function

Comment: @Timeless yep, have a submit async into validateAndSubmitForm, but Volune understand what's my problem

Comment: @DirkLachowski sorry, not think it was necessary show the code of the plugin because the problem does not focus on it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The browser has a single thread to interpret the javascript and update the interface. It can't do both simultaneously. You have to let some time to the browser so it can update the interface:

```
$("body").BusyIndicator(true,"Please wait");

setTimeout(function() {
    validateAndSubmitForm(); 

    $("body").BusyIndicator(true,"Saving");
}, 0);
```

`setTimeout` with a timer of 0 tells the browser to execute the function as soon as possible after it was able to update the interface (and do some other stuff like processing user input, ...)

Comment: thanks,i tryed to use setTimeout inside of the validateAndSubmitForm passing the same validateAndSubmitForm(indicated for an example that i found) as parameter , but some strange behavior happened, like many submits in the form.

I use your example and work fine,but after save one time, the first message isn't shown again.. but i alter  the timeout to 100 and seems to work, so, i can have any problem with this?

Comment: Here are some explanations about the queuing of javascript execution and UI updates : [Why is setTimeout(fn, 0) sometimes useful?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/779379/why-is-settimeoutfn-0-sometimes-useful) and video [High Performance JavaScript](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_fUGWFGUrUw) at 17:40